# WooCommerce package, flutter

Tags: flutter, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, flutter-packages

I am trying to add WooCommerce payment gateways through WooCommerce plugin on flutter, I've been having an error related to it, and I'm pretty sure that it's the package's fault.
I'd really like any kind of help related to it, since I am stuck on it, The error points at the order "int". I changed it to string still gave me the same error.

Here's the code---

Method:

```
  WooCommerce wooCommerce = WooCommerce(
    baseUrl: baseUrl,
    consumerKey: consumerKey,
    consumerSecret: consumerSecret,
    isDebug: true,
  );
  getPaymentGateways() async {
    gateways = await wooCommerce.getPaymentGateways();
  }
```

Error-

````
E/flutter (13771): #0      new WooPaymentGateway.fromJson (package:woocommerce/models/payment_gateway.dart:62:5)
E/flutter (13771): #1      WooCommerce.getPaymentGateways (package:woocommerce/woocommerce.dart:1413:39)
E/flutter (13771): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13771): #2      _CheckoutCardState.getPaymentGateways (package:flutter_auth/to_test/checkout.dart:34:34)
E/flutter (13771): #3      _CheckoutCardState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_auth/to_test/checkout.dart:100:23)
E/flutter (13771): #4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:779:19)
E/flutter (13771): #5      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:862:36)
E/flutter (13771): #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:182:24)
E/flutter (13771): #7      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:504:11)
E/flutter (13771): #8      BaseTapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:282:5)
E/flutter (13771): #9      BaseTapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:217:7)
E/flutter (13771): #10     PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:475:9)
E/flutter (13771): #11     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:76:12)
E/flutter (13771): #12     PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:122:9)```
````

WooPaymentGateway-

```
  String id;
  String title;
  String description;
  int order;
  bool enabled;
  String methodTitle;
  String methodDescription;
  List<String> methodSupports;
  WooPaymentGatewaySettings settings;
  WooPaymentGatewayLinks lLinks;

  WooPaymentGateway(
      {this.id,
        this.title,
        this.description,
        this.order,
        this.enabled,
        this.methodTitle,
        this.methodDescription,
        this.methodSupports,
        this.settings,
        this.lLinks}) : assert (id != null);

  WooPaymentGateway.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    title = json['title'];
    description = json['description'];
    order = json['order'];
    enabled = json['enabled'];
    methodTitle = json['method_title'];
    methodDescription = json['method_description'];
    methodSupports = json['method_supports'].cast<String>();
    settings = json['settings'] != null
        ? new WooPaymentGatewaySettings.fromJson(json['settings'])
        : null;
    lLinks = json['_links'] != null ? new WooPaymentGatewayLinks.fromJson(json['_links']) : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['title'] = this.title;
    data['description'] = this.description;
    data['order'] = this.order;
    data['enabled'] = this.enabled;
    data['method_title'] = this.methodTitle;
    data['method_description'] = this.methodDescription;
    data['method_supports'] = this.methodSupports;
    if (this.settings != null) {
      data['settings'] = this.settings.toJson();
    }
    if (this.lLinks != null) {
      data['_links'] = this.lLinks.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}
Let me know if I post the thing wrong<////>>??/////<<>>///
```